# I want to create elements of a list where each element comes from a satisfied nested for if loop statement

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, if-statement, nested-loops

```
str1 ="John000Doe000123"

list1 = []

for i in str1:
  if i == "0":
    continue
    
  
  list1.append(i)

print(list1)
```

OUTPUT: `['J', 'o', 'h', 'n', 'D', 'o', 'e', '1', '2', '3']`

but the output that I want is:

OUTPUT: `['John' , 'Doe' , '123']`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could split your string at character '0' and seek only valid entries from there:

```py
str1 ="John000Doe000123"

print([name for name in str1.split('0') if name])
# ['John', 'Doe', '123']
```

Comment: Can we also split using '000' and take out the - if name - (just a thought)

Comment: Yup that would also work (and probably more explicit) - especially if the delimiter is '000' and nothing else

Answer (score 2):

One of the simple solution using loop will be:

```
str1 ="John000Doe000123"

list1 = []
str2 = ""

for i in str1:
  if i == "0":
    if str2!="":
        list1.append(str2)
        str2 = ""
  else:
      str2 += i

if str2!= "":
    list1.append(str2)

print(list1)
```

Answer (score 2):

Just to cover all the splitting options, you can also do this with regular expressions to split on variable length sequences of `"0"`:

```
>>> import re
>>> re.split(r"0+", str1)
['John', 'Doe', '123']
```

(in this case it's not necessary to use a raw string but it's a good habit for regexes)

Answer (score 0):

Quick and easy, you want `s.split('000')`.

> For variable number of `0`'s, use a regex solution as mentioned by [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73920414/10237506).

```py
>>> str1 ="John000Doe000123"
>>> str1.split('000')
['John', 'Doe', '123']
```